# IIS reports 500 error code for URI too long

Tags: azure-web-app-service, http-status-codes

IIS (Azure App service) is reporting 500 error codes for an automated process that is sending requests with too long URLs.

We've asked the customer with the process to update their client but they haven't yet.

As a result, the IT director gets a 'An abnormal rise in failed request rate' alert in their inbox each time the automated process kicks off.

Is there a way to get IIS not to treat a client sending too long a URL as a 500 error - for example, it is a client error not a server error and '[414 URI too long](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.12)' would seem to be the correct error code for this, or even vanilla 400.

I don't want to increase the URI length - the client is failing and sending a long stack trace to us so we'd have to make it a silly size to accommodate their error.

Answer (score -1):

So it's a client error, it's caused by  browser's limit on the length of the URL string. Many browsers don't specify the maximum length, actually it's limited. For details about the limit you could refer to this doc: [What is the maximum length of a URL](https://boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html).

And in this [IE support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/208427/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer), there is a description

> the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the header and not in the URL.

So you need change the GET to POST to send data and you may need to change the server side to look for the data as POST instead of GET.

Comment: No, it is raised by IIS when the client exceeds the limit. We have asked the customer to change the client, and they probably will get around to it sometime (I have to ask our consultant to ask their representative who asks the technician responsible for the machine). This is a machine-to-machine API, nothing whatsoever to do with Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham, I'm not say it's the IE problem cause not just IE has the limit, other browsers have this limit. Just the IE support point the way to solve this limit.

Comment: There is no browser involved, it is a machine to machine API. If the client were imposing the limit, the client would not send the requests and the server would not be reporting an issue.